# Highcharts accessing all records from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I want to access all the records from database and populate the highchart. Currently my code is giving me one record. i want to access all the records  from `member_group`. The query should be changed. I tried alot But didn't got success.

PHP Code is :

```
$query="SELECT `group`.`name`,
        COUNT(`member`.`member_name`) as total
        FROM
        `group`,
        `member`,
        `member_group`
        WHERE `member_group`.`group_id` = `group`.`id`
        AND `member_group`.`member_id` = `member`.`id`
        GROUP BY `group`.`name`";

$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);

$name="";
$series="";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$name.="'".$row['name']."', ";
$series.=$row['total'].",";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve all your members, modify your query like this :

```
$query="SELECT `member`.`member_name`, `group`.`name`,
        FROM
        `group`,
        `member`,
        `member_group`
        WHERE `member_group`.`group_id` = `group`.`id`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! It returns all members ! I want to retrive all groups and their corresponding users !

Comment: It was indeed returning the group names and the number of members of theses groups. I've edited my answer to return all members and their respective groups. Is it what you want?

Comment: Sorry I am late here ! I was down for the last two days ! 
it return total members of group-A.
I want to return Like this, For example,
Group-A=10
Group-B=1
Group-C=05
Group-D=11
Group-E=25

Comment: Like my previous query then? If so, you just have to replace "member.member_name" by "count(member.member_name)" and add "GROUP BY group.name" at the end of the query.

Comment: bro its returns total members of all the groups and return Group-a Only

Comment: 49/group-A it returns like this.